# Why animation works only for the first slide and not for the others?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I am trying to make a simple slideshow with fade in animation using react hooks. But my animation works only on first slide and not for others.

This is function code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import './Homepage.css';

const Homepage = () => { 

  const slides = [
    "../../backgroundImages/1a.jpg",
    "../../backgroundImages/1b.jpg",
    "../../backgroundImages/1.jpg"
  ]; 
  
  const playRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    playRef.current = nextSlide;    
  }); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const play = setInterval(() => {      
      playRef.current();      
    }, 3000);
    
    return () => {
      clearInterval(play);
    }    
  }, []);  

  const nextSlide = () => {    
    slideIndex >= slides.length -1 
      ? setSlideIndex(0) 
      : setSlideIndex((slideIndex) => slideIndex + 1);
  }  

  return(       
    <img alt='background' src={slides[slideIndex]}
          className='homepage-background-div'
    />
  );
}
export default Homepage;
```

and this is css:

```
.homepage-background-div {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;   
  z-index: -1;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}  
@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

I have red answers for similar questions here on stackoverflow as well as many others articles and tutorials but was not able to solve the issue. Any help will be more than welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `key={slides[slideIndex]}` to tag img

```
<img
  alt="background"
  key={slides[slideIndex]}
  src={slides[slideIndex]}
  className="homepage-background-div"
/>
```

Comment: That is it. Thank You. If it is not too much to ask, could You give a short explanation?

Comment: The animation fires once, when the component is rendered. When you change the picture, the tag remains the same, so the animation does not start. And when the "key" is added, when the image changes, the new component is mounted and the animation starts.